# Should you check before setting a Django model's field?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a background service that imports django, and uses my django project's ORM directly.

It monitors something, in a loop, very often - every few seconds.
It goes through every user in my database, checks a condition, and based on that, sets a flag to either be True or False. I might have thousands of users in the database, so the efficiency here can add up.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if user.check():
            user.flag = True
        else:
            user.flag = False
        user.save()
```

I'm using MySQL as my database.

What I'm curious about is this: if a particular user has `.flag` set to `True`, am I doing a disk write every time I run `user.flag = True; user.save()`, even though nothing changed? Or is Django or MySQL smart enough not to do a disk write if nothing changed?

I assume a MySQL read operation is less expensive than a write operation. Would it make more sense to check the value of `user.flag`, and only try to set `user.flag` if the value actually changed? This would essentially be exchanging a database read for a database write, from what I understand (except in cases where something actually changed, in which case, first a read is performed, and then a write).

Note: This is just a basic example. I'm not actually dealing with users.

Comment: In your case, you've already read. The `user` object already contains the current `flag` value. It would cost you nothing to read from the value.

And yes, you're correct that a database write is made even when nothing changed.

Comment: @KevinLee does the database write anything to disk in such a case? Does it depend on the database? Even if it doesn't write the value to disk, does it maybe write metadata about when the value was last updated to disk?

Comment: You can safely assume that an "attempt" to update the database is made. Whether or not your database actually attempts any writes could depend on the database. I would believe that the "effort" by your backend is equivalent in either case: a hit to the database. You can probably improve performance by only calling `.save()` when the flag needs to be changed, as @schillingt describes in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move the logic of `check` into a `.filter()` clause, that would be best. That way you could do:

```
User.objects.filter(match_check, flag=False).update(flag=True)
User.objects.filter(~Q(match_check), flag=True).update(flag=False)
```

Or if you could annotate the value:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    new_flag=some_check,
).exclude(flag=F('new_flag')).update(flag= ('new_flag'))
```

Otherwise if you can't then maybe do it like this:

```
new_flag = user.check()
if new_flag != user.flag:
    user.flag = new_flag
    user.save(update_fields=['flag']) # This will only update that single column.
```